# Does my ISP know what sites I have visited if I am using Tor?

Tags: security, privacy

For Example:
You -> Tor Entry node -> Tor Middle Node -> Tor Exit Node -> Website

The website i visiting only sees the IP address of the Tor Exit Node right ?
but which one isp sees ? tor entry node ? or tor exit node ?

Please if you are sure answer me, thanks a lot

Comment: [You really need to see this .](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/906/does-my-isp-know-what-sites-i-have-visited-if-i-am-using-tor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP only sees that the Tor network is being used.

The route is:

You > Tor Client > Your ISP > Tor network > Tor network > Tor network > Tor network > Tor destination.

Comment: thank you for your help, so they know i'm using tor but they don't know what i'm doing or what sites i'm visiting right ?

Comment: Yes. All they see is that you connect to the first tor node. In the same sense, the end node does not know where you are from. That's the entire idea behind tor.

Comment: the key here is that TOR uses encryption to protect the payload passing through the tunnel, so that it appears to be a binary blob.